# Unable to swipe down when spinners included

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-relativelayout

My Android app uses the given layout (consider that there are about 7 more AutoCompleteTextViews and 5 more Spinner) however I am not able to swipe down the screen. Is the problem somehow connected with the view or more likely with activity ? Any help would be great since I am stuck here.

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.meg.myapplication.Activity"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:baselineAligned="false">

<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/view1"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textColor="#a9a9a9"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    />

...

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

...

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Where is you java code?

Comment: did u add scrollview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a scrollview

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1">

<AutoCompleteTextView
android:id="@+id/view1"
android:layout_width="300dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:inputType="textPersonName"
android:maxLines="1"
android:singleLine="true"
android:imeOptions="actionDone"
android:textSize="15sp"
android:padding="10dp"
android:textColor="#a9a9a9"
android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
/>

 ...

<Spinner
android:id="@+id/spinner1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>

...

</ScrollView>
```